What does an inner product between kets of different dimensions mean?
To compute the Euclidean distance between two classical vectors $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{B}$, the following procedure was suggested. First, encode the vectors as quantum states:
$$
\vec{A} \rightarrow |A\rangle = \frac{1}{|\vec{A}|}\sum_i{A_i}|i\rangle, \\
\vec{B} \rightarrow |B\rangle = \frac{1}{|\vec{B}|}\sum_i{B_i}|i\rangle. 
$$
Then cleverly construct these two states:
$$
|\phi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{Z}}\bigl(|\vec{A}| |0\rangle - |\vec{B}| |1\rangle \bigr), \\
|\psi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\bigl(|0\rangle \otimes |A\rangle + |1\rangle \otimes |B\rangle \bigr).
$$
The goal is to use a swap test and for that, one has to compute the inner product of:
$$
  \langle \phi | \psi \rangle \\
  = \left\langle 
     \frac{1}{\sqrt{Z}}\left(|\vec{A}| |0\rangle - |\vec{B}||1\rangle \right) \;\middle|\; 
     \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|0\rangle \otimes |A\rangle + |1\rangle \otimes |B\rangle \right)
     \right\rangle \nonumber \\
$$
and with some tricks one arrives at
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2Z}} \left( |\vec{A}| |A\rangle - |\vec{B}| |B\rangle \right).
$$
The problem is: The inner product is mathematically not defined, the vectors have different sizes. The results still add up nicely and I don't understand why. Is there a better way to derive this?

The ket $|\phi\rangle$ represents a state of a single qubit $q$. The ket $|\psi\rangle$ represents a composite state of the qubit $q$ and an auxiliary system $a$. We can make this explicit by adding labels
\begin{align}
|\phi\rangle_q &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{Z}}\bigl(|\vec{A}| |0\rangle_q - |\vec{B}| |1\rangle_q \bigr)\tag1 \\
|\psi\rangle_{qa} &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\bigl(|0\rangle_q \otimes |A\rangle_a + |1\rangle_q \otimes |B\rangle_a \bigr).\tag2
\end{align}
The inner product is performed on matching subsystems. For example, the inner product of $|0\rangle_q$ and $|+\rangle_q$ is a scalar
\begin{align}
\langle 0|_q\cdot|+\rangle_q = \langle 0|+\rangle_q = \frac{1}{\sqrt2}\tag3
\end{align}
but the inner product of $|0\rangle_q$ and $|{++}\rangle_{qa}$ is a ket
\begin{align}
\langle 0|_q\cdot\left(|{++}\rangle_{qa}\right) = \langle 0|+\rangle_q\cdot |+\rangle_a=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}|+\rangle_a.\tag4
\end{align}
Therefore, the cross-terms in $\langle\phi|\psi\rangle$, in which the value of the qubit differs between $|\phi\rangle$ and $|\psi\rangle$, disappear.

It should be noted that this subspace matching is equivalent to looking at $|\phi\rangle$ really as $|\phi\rangle_q\otimes{\bf1}_a$. So when $\langle\phi|\psi\rangle$ is computed it is really $(\langle\phi|_q\otimes{\bf1}a)(|\psi\rangle{qa})$, which yields a vector on $a$, as desired.
